# maven.exasol.com artifactory link not working

Tags: exasol

Fail to use exasol repository, the link https://maven.exasol.com/artifactory/exasol-releases redirects to the exasol.com new homepage.

This fails to get the dependencies I need:

```
<repository>  
<id>exasol-maven-repo</id>  
<name>Exasol Repository</name>  
<url>https://maven.exasol.com/artifactory/exasol-releases</url>;  
</repository>
```

Tried to open the link with curl and got nothing.

curl -O https://maven.exasol.com/artifactory/exasol-releases/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.0/scala-compiler-2.12.0.pom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMLdK.png)

Answer (score 1):

`maven.exasol.com` is discontinued. If you want to get e.g. the jdbc driver, you can use maven central now. See [JDBC documentation](https://docs.exasol.com/db/latest/connect_exasol/drivers/jdbc.htm).

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.exasol</groupId>
        <artifactId>exasol-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It looks like you are interested in some scala packages. `import-export-udf-common-scala` is also available on maven central now: https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/com.exasol/import-export-udf-common-scala_2.13/1.0.0